# Android studio connection with mobile phone device (Galaxy note2) is disconnected frequently while debugging

Tags: android

When I make a android project and running in debugging mode, connection with mobile phone device is disconnected in android studio.

If I unplug and plug, it is reconnected.
and running in debugging mode again, disconnected too.

It's very annoying and this situation makes very frequently.

Who's know solution of this problem?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found out a solution of this problem. :D

I refered this :
http://www.droidforums.net/threads/frequently-connecting-and-disconnecting.11263/